# Text File isn't being created

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, scripting, applescript

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    NSAppleScript *script = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:@"tell application \"Safari\" to return URL of tabs of window 1"];
    NSDictionary *scriptError = nil;
    NSAppleEventDescriptor *descriptor = [script executeAndReturnError:&scriptError];
    if(scriptError) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@",scriptError);
    } else {
        NSAppleEventDescriptor *listDescriptor = [descriptor  coerceToDescriptorType:typeAEList];
        NSMutableArray *result = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for (NSInteger i = 1; i <= [listDescriptor numberOfItems]; ++i) {
            NSAppleEventDescriptor *URLDescriptor = [listDescriptor descriptorAtIndex:i];
            [result addObject: URLDescriptor.stringValue];
    }
    NSString *content = [result componentsJoinedByString:@","];

    NSData *fileContents = [content dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:@"~/Desktop/foo.txt"
                                            contents:fileContents
                                          attributes:nil];
    NSLog(@"Result: %@", [result copy]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The problem with my code right now, is every thing works normally(printing out the array of URLs etc. But when I check I see that foo.txt isn't being created? What is wrong with my application.

and another of my question is on my applescript (2nd line), I can only get URL of window 1, how can I get all windows?

Any answers would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Tilde expansion is handled by a Unix shell.  Objective-C won't automatically expand that string into an absolute path to your Desktop directory.

You need to use `stringByExpandingTildeInPath` or

```
NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDesktopDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
```

to construct a proper path for `createFileAtPath`.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the second question, `tell app "Safari" to get URL of every tab of every window` should return a list of lists of URL strings (caveat any bugs/limitations in the application's Apple event support).

You may also want to consider using the [AppleScriptObjC](http://appscript.sourceforge.net/asoc.html) bridge, which does all the data conversion and calling work for you. While still not ideal, it's not frustratingly tedious like NSAppleScript/NSAppleEventDescriptor or frustratingly broken like ScriptingBridge, so is usually the easiest and and most reliable way to talk to "AppleScriptable" apps from ObjC.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question you could just use:

```
[content writeToFile:[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingString: @"/Desktop/foo.txt"]
     atomically:YES
       encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
          error:nil]
```

Instead of:

```
NSData *fileContents = [content dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:@"~/Desktop/foo.txt"
                                        contents:fileContents
                                      attributes:nil];
```

`content` is the variable you used in your code.